# Nestjs exception inside a loop

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a loop like this:

```js
async sendMessage(data:MessageDto,userId:string){
     
        data.targets.forEach (async (channel) => {

            
            let gateway = await this.getUserChannel(userId,channel.channelId);
            
            
            switch (channel.target) {
                case 'Telegram':                            
                    this.telegramService.sendMessageGateway(gateway,data)
                    break;            
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

where getUserChannel function is:

```js
    async getUserChannel(userId: string, channelId: string): Promise<IGateway> {
        const currentChannel = await this.GatewayModel.findOne({ userId: userId, channelId: channelId })
        if (!currentChannel) {
            throw new HttpException(`Gateway Not Found`, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);        
        }
        return currentChannel;
    }
```

If the getUserChannel return a HttpException, Nest doesn't return the error in my response.
I can try the same function (getUserChannel), outside the foreach, and I can retrieve the response with 404 Status code.

**UPDATE**

After the answers, my code is:

```js
let datas = data.targets.map(async (channel) => {
            let gateway = await this.getUserChannel(userId, channel.channelId);
            switch (channel.target) {
                case 'Telegram':
                    await this.telegramService.sendMessageGateway(gateway, data)
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        })

        let allPromise = Promise.allSettled(datas)

        const statuses = await allPromise;
        console.log(statuses)
```

It could help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype` looping methods do not handle async methods correctly, and are actually synchronous in nature, so the execution fires and forgets about the promise and eventually resolves to a 200 even if there is an error thrown. To get around this. you can return the promises from a `Array.prototype.map` and use `await Promise.all(promises)` to get proper error handling if one of them tends up throwing an error.

Comment: For some use cases, `await Promise.allSettled(promises)` is better than `await Promise.all(promises)`. `all` will error on the first promise that rejects, whereas `allSettled` lets you iterate over each promise's results and handle multiple rejections. For example, this lets you log each failure as opposed to just the first one.

Comment: Thanks guys, I edited my questions after your amazing answers. Thanks a lot